# Using .Findindex etc F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to use the findindex function on a ResizeArray, howevever I'm not sure how to use it.
The Array is called inventory, of type Gitem, I am trying to find the index of an object in the array, If I can't I'll just create a function to do so but I would like to learn how to use FindIndex.

Also, with ResizeArrays, which function allows you to replace an index with a value?I assume insert pushes the positions in the array forward and keeps the previous value, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Seq.findIndex` on a `ResizeArray<'a>` since it implements `IEnumerable<'a>`, which is the same as `seq<'a>`:

```
ResizeArray ["a"; "b"; "c"] |> Seq.findIndex (fun s -> s = "b")
// 1
```

`ResizeArray` is just another name for .NET's `System.Collections.Generic.List`. There aren't any F# core functions for working with it as far as I know. You can change the item at an index using the syntax for indexers and mutation:

```
let xs = ResizeArray ["a"; "b"; "c"]
xs.[1] <- "-"

xs
// val it : System.Collections.Generic.List<string> = seq ["a"; "-"; "c"]
```